# Using PyTorch for computing derivative of a function

Tags: python, pytorch, derivative

When I execute the code below:

```py
import torch 

def g(x):
    return 4*x + 3
x=3.0
g_hat=torch.tensor(g(x), requires_grad= True)
g_hat.backward()
```

I get the following output:

```py
>>>g_hat.grad
tensor(1.)
```

But this is not the result that I was expecting to get from my code above... what I want to do is, I want to find the value of dg/dx, at `x = 3.0` (so in the example above, the correct output should be `tensor(4.)`).
How can I achieve this with PyTorch? or if I can't carry out this task with PyTorch, how can I do this type of task easily on Python?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor([1.0]),requires_grad=True)
y = 4 * x + 3
y.backward()
x.grad
```

Works fine.

Comment: The `autograd.Variable` API [has been deprecated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated) since version 0.4.0. To improve clarity I recommend `x = torch.Tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)` instead.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have a follow up question. can PyTorch do vector calculus? for example, computing a second derivative with respect to a vector? If yes, how can I compute a second derivative of a function with respect to a vector on Pytorch?

Comment: @IgorRivin thank you so much! This is very helpful! :)